# Elixir - Folder does not copy if there is a dot in the directory name

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

I am using Laravel 5.2 with elixir.

I have found that if I use elixir on a directory that contains a dot, it will only copy the folder, but not the contents inside.

For example consider copying a folder called `a.something` at the root of the project:

```
exlixir(function(mix) {
    mix.copy('a.something', 'public/a.something');
});
```

The above will only make an empty directory called `a.something` and not copy its contents.

On the other hand the following works fine if the folder is called `a`:

```
exlixir(function(mix) {
    mix.copy('a', 'public/a');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was a bug and is now fixed!

https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/559